# query for retrieving data from view is not working

Tags: java, mysql, view

I created a view as an integration of three tables but when I retrieve the data in the view using query ... the system stop working

I create a view using this query:

```
PreparedStatement statement1 = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) con1.prepareStatement("
CREATE VIEW mcps1_patients_view AS 
SELECT a.PatientID
     , PatientGender
     , PatientDateOfBirth 
     , PatientMaritalStatus
     , a.Ad_ID
     , Ad_StartDateAndTime
     , Ad_EndDateAndTime
     , d.ICD10CM_Code
     , d.PrimaryDiagnosisDescription 
  From patientcorepopulatedtable p 
  JOIN  admissionscorepopulatedtable a 
  JOIN admissionsdiagnosescorepopulatedtable d  
");  
result1 = statement1.execute();
System.out.print("connected");
```

and I want to make a query on the created view ...

```
PreparedStatement statement4 = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) con2.prepareStatement(" SELECT * From mcps2_patients_view where P_ID= ? ");  
    statement4.setString(1, Hospital2_id);
    result4 = statement4.executeQuery();
    System.out.print("connected \n")
```

but the last query is not working its stopped working

what is the problem ??? 
and how can I solve it?

Comment: So there's no relationship between these tables?

Comment: You are creating a view called mcps1_patients_view and querying mcps2_patients_view, and the column P_ID isn't declared either - are you sure it's the right view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing some things, the query sintax you are passing at the creation of the view should be native SQL. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String))

> Creates a PreparedStatement object for sending parameterized SQL statements to the database

What you pasted there seems to be JPQL. The SQL Join statement needs also the `ON` part to specify what column the join is being done. Something like: `SELECT... FROM patient p join patient_admission pa on pa.patient_id = p.id`

Is that a typo? I expect your code creating the view thows an exception.

Comment: @monaalhumud, why are you creating the view from Java? You normally create the view from a database client and then you use he name of the view in Java